# Working with Dynamic Form and field States in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, forms, swiftui, dynamic

I'm kind of lost on how to work with states with Dynamic forms.
I surely cannot create states for each Field because I don't know how many fields are there as these Forms are basically built from a JSON Response.

Here is basically what I have right now which is what I'm looking to change.
Initially I created a state for each field back when the forms were not built dynamically and now I'm stuck on how to proceed.

I thought about using Dictionary but I ain't sure how good of a solution is that.

```
    @State var textfieldText: String = ""
    @State var SKU: String = ""
    @State private var showScanner: Bool = false
    var currentForm: FormModel
    @State var RecordDate: Date = Date.now
    @State var Formresponse: [String: Any] = [:]//This one is set to any because the value can vary from a string to [] to even a whole object
```

How I'm Rendering my form :

```
          ForEach(currentForm.item, id:\.idf) { it in
                
                        if (!it.questionItem.hidden)
                        {
                            switch it.questionItem.questionType {
                        case .dateQuestion :
                                    DateField(title: it.title, currentDate: $RecordDate)
                        case .choiceQuestion:
                            Text("choice question")
                        case .scannerQuestion:
                            ScannerField(title: it.title, SKU: $SKU, showScanner: $showScanner)
                            
                        case .textQuestion:
                            TextQuestionField(title: it.title, email: currentForm.owner, text: $textfieldText)
                            }
                        }
                    
                }
```

I'll eventually have to submit this data in a form of dictionary which is why I thought about using a Dict ["fieldID":"FieldInput","fieldId2":"FieldInput2"..]

Comment: can you add a json example ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you only need one `State` and that is for the `formResponse`. You can pass that as a `Binding` to each input field view and within that view you can create a custom `Binding` to get and set the answer to the `formResponse`. Something like this:

```
struct FormFieldInputView: View {
    @Binding var formResponse: [String: Any]
    let field: String

    var body: some View {
        TextField(field, text: Binding(
            get: {
                formResponse[field] as? String ?? ""
            },
            set: { newValue in
                formResponse[field] = newValue
            })
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

define **enum** for the questions type:

```
enum FormItemType {
   case dataQuestion
   case choiceQuestion
   case scannerQuestion
   case textQuestion
}
```

define the item model for the questions type:

```
struct FormItemModel : Identifiable {
    var type : FormItemType
    var itemObject : Any
    var userInput : String?
    let id : UUID
}
```

define the form view model:

```
final class FormModel : ObservableObject {        
    @Published var items : [FormItemModel] = []
}
```

and the view :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var formViewModel: FormModel
    
    @Binding var currentInput : String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(formViewModel.items, id: \.id, content: { item in
                
                switch item.type {
                case .dataQuestion:
                    Text(item.itemObject as? String ?? "")
                    
                case .scannerQuestion:
                    Text("\(item.itemObject as? Int ?? 0 )")
                    
                case .choiceQuestion:
                    if let dic = item.itemObject as? [String:String]{
                        VStack{
                            Text(dic["Q"]!)
                            Text(dic["A1"]!)
                            Text(dic["A2"]!)
                            Text(dic["A3"]!)
                        }
                    }
                    
                case .textQuestion:
                    
                    VStack{
                        Text(item.itemObject as? String ?? "")
                        TextEditor(text: $currentInput)
                    }
                }
            })//ForEach
        }//List
    }
}//View
```

and here's the dummy values for the form:

```
items = [FormItemModel(type: .textQuestion, itemObject: "Tell Me About Yourself...", id: UUID()),
             FormItemModel(type: .choiceQuestion,
                           itemObject: ["Q":"How much is 1+1?", "A1":"1", "A2":"2", "A3":"3"],
                           id: UUID()),
             FormItemModel(type: .scannerQuestion, itemObject: 1110111011, id: UUID())
    ]
```

and the result:
[image]

Comment: This is more or less what I did actually. 
Thank you very much, one question though, if that enum is pointing(indirectly) to another struct, how can I access the values in it ? 
For example I have four structs that match the question types each. and they have bool values in them. Is there a way that I can access those values ?

Comment: Actually I just noticed that I have issues in my decoder.

Comment: your question is unclear - enums don't point, they are value typed.  
In my example the value is in itemObject. maybe it'd be more correct to call this attribute 'valueObj'